How to use Selenium for Opta data?
I'm trying to get Opta event data from a football (soccer) match. It has a link address but when trying to access it I just get a 10300 Error code.
The only place I can view the data is under 'Sources' in the dev tools where it's under a folder called api.performfeeds.com. How do I access Sources with selenium?
I've tried api requests and much other stuff. I'm able to scrape to most other data sites but this one (scoresway.com) is tricky.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Have you asked Opta to whitelist the IP address from where you are making the request?
